# Adaptedness of random variables

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, stopping-times

Suppose we have an RCLL adapted process $(X_t)$. Moreover we are given a stopping time $T$. We define $\mathcal{F}_T=\{A\in\mathcal{F}\mid A\cap\{T\le t\}\in \mathcal{F}_t, \text{ for all }t\ge0\}$. Now I have several question concerning measurability of products of r.v.:

1. Why is $X_T\mathbf1_{\{T<t\}}\in\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge t}$?
2. For $H\in\mathcal{F}_t$, why is $H\mathbf1_{\{T\ge t\}}\in \mathcal{F}_T$?
3. Why does 2. imply: $E[X_T\mathbf1_{\{T\ge t\}}|\mathcal{F}_{t\wedge T}]=E[X_T|\mathcal{F}_t]\mathbf1_{T\ge t}$?

where $\mathbf1_A$ denotes the indicator function of a set $A$.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I find it a bit difficult to understand your notation. I am very much interested in stochastic processes and measure theory, but I miss a bit of definitions in your posts. If you give them, your post will be useful not only to the specialist (probably not, because he is already a specialist), but also to other interested people.

Comment: @AndréCaldas: I think the terms used here are pretty standard (maybe apart from the "$X$ belongs to a sigma-algebra" notation for measurability). What definitions in particular are you looking for?

Comment: @StefanHansen: First, there are two different definitions for $\mathcal{F}_T$. $H\mathbf1_{\{T\ge t\}}$ is a set? And of course, I could search by my self, but I don't have any idea what a RCLL adapted process is.

Comment: @AndréCaldas: Alright, I understand your confusion. When he writes $H\in\mathcal{F}_t$, he means that $H:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable so $H\mathbf{1}_{\{T\geq t\}}$ is the mapping $\omega\mapsto H(\omega)\mathbf{1}_{\{T(\omega)\geq t\}}$. RCLL means right-continuous with left limits and is synonymous with the french cádlág. Where do you see two definitions of $\mathcal{F}_T$?

Comment: @StefanHansen: The definition of $\mathcal{F}_T$ uses $\mathcal{F}_t$, including the case where $t = T$. Not to mention that $\mathcal{F}_t$ is not defined. Later, we don't know which definition to use for $\mathcal{F}_{t\wedge T}$. Of course, I can imagine about two or three possibilities for what $\mathcal{F}_t$ really means. But I think this kind of thing should be properly defined so we don't go discussing, each one with his own definition.

Comment: @AndréCaldas: "The definition of $\mathcal{F}_T$ uses $\mathcal{F}_t$, including the case where $t=T$" - No it doesn't ($T$ is not among "for all $t\geq 0$").

Comment: @StefanHansen: Ah... Ok. $T$ is a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take the following results for granted. If you're not familiar with them, you should prove them.

> **Result 1**: Let $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ be a mapping. Then $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable if and only if $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}$ for all $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $0\notin B$.
>
> **Result 2**: If $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are two stopping times and $A\in\mathcal{F}_\sigma$, then $A\cap \{\sigma\leq \tau\}\in\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$.

1) Since $\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge t}=\mathcal{F}_T\cap \mathcal{F}_t$, we need to show that $X_T\mathbf{1}_{T<t}$ is both $\mathcal{F}_T$- and $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable.

The $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurability: Since $(X_t)$ is RCLL it is also jointly measurable, and hence $X_T$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable. Since also $\{T<t\}\in\mathcal{F}_T$ we have that $X_T\mathbf{1}_{T<t}$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable.

The $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurability: For $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $0\notin B$ we have
$$
(X_T\mathbf{1}_{T<t})^{-1}(B)=X_T^{-1}(B)\cap \{T<t\}=\bigcup_n \left(X_T^{-1}(B)\cap\left\{T\leq t-\tfrac1n\right\}\right)\in\mathcal{F}_t,
$$
by definition of $\mathcal{F}_T$.

2) $(H\mathbf{1}_{T\geq t})^{-1}(B)=H^{-1}(B)\cap \{T\geq t\}\in\mathcal{F}_{T}$ for all $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $0\notin B$ by Result 2.

3) Using Result 2 with $\sigma=t$ and $\tau=T$, we have $A\cap\{T\geq t\}\in\mathcal{F}_{T}$ for all $A\in\mathcal{F}_t$.

Now, let $Y={\rm E}[X_T\mid\mathcal{F}_t]$. Then we have to argue that $Y\mathbf{1}_{T\geq t}$ is $\mathcal{F}_{t\wedge T}$-measurable and that ${\rm E}[X_T\mathbf{1}_{T\geq t}\mathbf{1}_A]={\rm E}[Y\mathbf{1}_{T\geq t}\mathbf{1}_A]$ for all $A\in\mathcal{F}_{t\wedge T}$.

The measurability follows from the fact that for $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $0\notin B$ we have
$$
\left(Y\mathbf{1}_{T\geq t}\right)^{-1}(B)=Y^{-1}(B)\cap\{T\geq t\}\in\mathcal{F}_T\cap\mathcal{F}_t
$$
since $Y^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}_t$ and $\{T\geq t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$.

For the last part, let $A\in\mathcal{F}_{T\wedge t}$, then
$$
{\rm E}[X_T\mathbf{1}_{T\geq t}\mathbf{1}_A]={\rm E}[X_T\mathbf{1}_{\{T\geq t\}\cap A}]={\rm E}[Y\mathbf{1}_{\{T\geq t\}\cap A}]={\rm E}[Y\mathbf{1}_{T\geq t}\mathbf{1}_A],
$$
where the middle equality follows by the definition of $Y$ and the fact that $\{T\geq t\}\cap A\in\mathcal{F}_t$.

---

Proof of Result 1: Suppose $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}$ for all $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $0\notin B$. Now suppose that $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $0\in B$. Then $0\notin B^c$, and hence $X^{-1}(B^c)\in\mathcal{F}$ and therefore also
$$
X^{-1}(B)=(X^{-1}(B^c))^c\in\mathcal{F}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There was a typo in my question, second point. It should be $\mathcal{F}_T$. I edited my question. I will check your answer

Comment: I've checked your answer carefully and I have some questions: for 1) I have another argument why $X_T\in\mathcal{F}_T$. How exactly is your argument using jointly measurability working?. 3) Why is $(Y\mathbf1_{T\ge t})^{-1}\in\mathcal{F}_T\cap \mathcal{F}_t$? I see that both are $\mathcal{F}_t$ for fixed $t$. Last: Could you provide a source for result 1 and 2?

Comment: Thanks again for adding a proof of result 2. Have you seen my additional question in the previous comment?

Comment: I'm using jointly measurability to ensure that the composition $\omega\mapsto (T(\omega),\omega)\mapsto X_{T(\omega)}(\omega)$ is still measurable (the last of the two $\mapsto$). For the last question, note that $\{T\geq t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$ by definition of being a stopping time and that $Y^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}_t$ since $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable. Moreover, $Y^{-1}(B)\cap \{T\geq t\}\in\mathcal{F}_T$ by Result 2 with $\sigma=t$ and $\tau=T$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stefan!

Comment: You're welcome!